# "Network unreachable" after adding ovs bridge

Tags: centos, network-interface, internet, bridge, openstack

I'm deploying openstack cloud on centos 7 and during installation, I'd added an external bridge to one of my interfaces that is connected to the internet by using these commands:

```
$ ovs-vsctl add-br br-ex
$ ovs-vsctl add-port br-ex eno1
```

then I lost my connection.
I've edited ifcfg files like this:

ifcfg-eno1:

```
    TYPE=OVSPort
    BOOTPROTO="none"
    DEVICETYPE=ovs
    OVS_BRIDGE=br-ex
    DEFROUTE="yes"
    PEERDNS="yes"
    PEERROUTES="yes"
    IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
    IPV6INIT="yes"
    IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
    IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
    IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
    IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
    IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
    IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
    NAME="eno1"
    UUID="07613f35-e629-425d-8318-5ffeb60b7587"
    DEVICE="eno1
    ONBOOT="yes"
```

ifcfg-br-ex:

```
DEVICE=br-ex
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
DEVICETYPE=ovs
TYPE=OVSBridge
```

after that by following [this guide](http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/faq/issues/) , I entered these commands:

```
$ ip addr flush dev eno1
$ ip addr add 10.1.79.124/24 dev br-ex
$ ip link set br-ex up
```

then I restarted network services and when I tried to ping 4.2.2.4 ,this error happened:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

also I'd read openstack docs and these topics and guides, but still have problem:

```
https://www.rdoproject.org/networking/networking-in-too-much-detail/
http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/faq/issues/
```

I get confused and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem solved by entering these commands:

```
ip link set br-ex up
ip address add dev br-ex 10.1.79.124 netmask 255.255.255.0
ip route add default via 10.1.79.124
```

Missing command was : `ip route add default via 10.1.79.124`